# ¿Cómo cargar un enlace de URL en Bundle asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Mi consulta es la siguiente, deseo saber como puedo cargar un cdn desde un `bundle`, yo lo hago así pero cuando es url externa no se carga

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/style").Include(
 "~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",//(esta si es llamada)                 
 "~/https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css",// ( esta no carga )                                
));
```

Comment: Intenta quitar `~/` antes de `https:`

Comment: sugerencia: descarga esos estilos y realiza lo mismo que hiciste con bootstrap

Comment: lo pense, pero queria saber si existe la forma de hacerlo sin la necesidad de descargarlo.

Comment: al quitar el ~/ te sale elrror al usar el Bundle en mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, según la documentación de microsoft tanto el constructor de [StyleBundle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.optimization.stylebundle(v=vs.110).aspx) como el de [ScriptBundle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.optimization.scriptbundle(v=vs.110).aspx) soportan sólo un CDN (el cúal se recibe como segúndo parámetro `string CdnPath`)

Ahora, en tu caso, hay 2 cosas a tener en cuenta, primero, si la aplicación se está compilando en modo `Debug` debes activar `EnableOptimizations`

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

En caso de estarla corriendo en modo `Relase` no es necesario

También debes activar `UseCdn`

```
BundleTable.Bundles.UseCdn = true;
```

En tu caso, suponiendo que estas trabajando en modo `Debug` deberías hacer lo siguiente

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/DataTables","https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"));
BundleTable.Bundles.UseCdn = true;
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Luego, en tu vista deberías cargar ambos `bundle`, en caso de que necesites que sea uno solo, deberías conseguir un cdn que tenga ambos.

Saludos!

Comment: Para usar ciertas sentencias en modo `Debug` sería bueno que incluyeras las [directivas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) para ello: `#if DEBUG`, `#if (!DEBUG)`, `#else` y `#endif`. Sería una respuesta más completa, creo yo.